# Ajax not sending FormData

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I have several other identical functions working successfully but I can not get this last bit to work (The photo being 'uploaded' is not storing in the database). Any help at all would be much appreciated. *I understand the mysql statements are a deprecated version and will be changed.*

***Ajax function***

```
function uploadProLicense5() {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var dataFive = new FormData();
    dataFive.append("professionalLicensePhotoFifthProivder", document.querySelector("#professionalLicensePhotoFifthProivder").files[0]);
    ajax.open("POST", "home.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState === 4) {
            if (ajax.status === 200) {
                // OK
                $('#success_prolicense5').fadeIn().html("Photo Saved");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#success_prolicense5').fadeOut("Slow");
                }, 2000);
                // here you can use the result (ajax.responseText)
            } else {
                // not OK
                alert('failed to upload photo, please try again');
            }
        }
    };
    ajax.send(dataFive);
}
```

***Html***

```
<div class="well col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" id="professionalphotoRow5">
    <div class="text-center">
        <label>Upload professional license photo:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <label id="label5thproviderPro">for 5th provider</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-offset-4">
        <input name="professionalLicensePhotoFifthProivder" id="professionalLicensePhotoFifthProivder" class="filestyle" data-input="false"
               type="file" accept="image/*">
    </div>
    <?php
    $savedTxt = "Photo Saved";
    $notSavedTxt = "Photo Not Saved";
    if (!empty($userRow[pro_license_photo_provider_five])) {
        echo "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-offset-4' style='color: greenyellow;'>" . "</i> " . $savedTxt;
    }
    ?>
    <br>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-offset-4">
        <input id="saveProfessionalPhoto5" type="button" class="btn btn-default"
               name="saveProfessionalPhoto5" onclick="uploadProLicense5()"
               value="upload photo" style="background-color: #1d2b5c; color: white"/>
    </div>
    <span id="success_prolicense5" class="text-success col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-offset-4"></span>
</div>
```

***PHP***

```
$db_pro_license_img_provider_five = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['professionalLicensePhotoFifthProivder']['tmp_name']));
$pro_image_data_provider_five = base64_encode($userRow[pro_license_photo_provider_five]);
$pro_data_provider_five = substr($pro_image_data_provider_five, strpos($pro_image_data_provider_five, ","));
if(!empty($db_pro_license_img_provider_five)){
    $sql = "UPDATE `wp_form` SET
    `pro_license_photo_provider_five`='$db_pro_license_img_provider_five'
    WHERE id =" . $_SESSION['user'];
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_form WHERE id=" . $_SESSION['user']);
    $userRow = mysql_fetch_array($res);
}
```

Here's my network request

[image]

And then my empty blob : (

[image]

Comment: 1) Have you started session at the very top of your *home.php* page? 2) From where you're getting this `$userRow[pro_license_photo_provider_five]` value in *home.php* page?

Comment: indeed I have. It successfully works with 9 other photo upload functions that are identical to this one.

Comment: Aside: I think you mean `deprecated`. Depreciated means something totally different.

Comment: @JordanS no, it completely depends on the application. A good RDBMS can totally handle image storage, though there are some things you should do to keep the schema efficient.

Comment: OP if you're using jQuery, why aren't you using the jQuery ajax facilities?

Comment: @Pointy I'm not sure how I would rewrite the current function to match the syntax of an ajax facility. Would you care to illustrate?

Comment: @MrBoutte' [jQuery Ajax facilities](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)